# Problema con métodos HTTP en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravelcollective

Lo que pasa es que tengo un problema con los métodos HTTP en Laravel. El problema es que al utilizar el método PUT me da el siguiente error: **The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.** Estoy utilizando laravel collective para el form. Intenté también hacerlo con campos escondidos pero aun asi sigue ese error.

Código del form:

```
@extends("layouts.app")

@section("content")
   <div class="container white">
      <h1>Nuevo Producto</h1>
      <!--Formulario-->
      {!! Form::open(['url' => $url, 'method' => $method]) !!}
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::text('title',$product->title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Titulo...']) }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::number('price',$product->price, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Precio de tu producto en centavos de dólar...']) }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::textarea('description',$product->description, ['class' =>  'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Descripción...']) }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group text-right">
            <a href="{{url('/products')}}">Regresar al listado de productos</a>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success">
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
  </div>
@endsection
```

Código de la vista para actualizar datos:

```
@extends("layouts.app")
@section("content")
<div class="container white">
    <h1>Editar Producto</h1>
    <!--Formulario-->
    @include('products.form', ['product' => $product, 'url' => '/products/'.$product->id, 'method' => 'PUT'])
</div>
@endsection
```

Código del controlador:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);

    $product->title = $request->title;
    $product->description = $request->description;
    $product->price = $request->price;
    $product->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    if($product->save()){
        return redirect("/products");
    }else{
        return view("products.edit", ["product" => $product]);
    }
}
```

Rutas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Y dónde está el input csrf ?

Comment: Ya habia puesto el csrf cuando ponia los campos ocultos pero aun asi.

Comment: Y el archivo de rutas de Laravel tiene esa ruta con verbo PUT.?

Comment: En las rutas lo tengo como Route::resource

Comment: Tengo una duda, en esta linea `@include('products.form', ['product' => $product, 'url' => '/products/'.$product->id, 'method' => 'PATCH'])` es `'method' => 'PATCH']` o `'method' => 'PATH']`?

Comment: Se me olvido agregar, cuando usas formularios, debes agregar `@CSRF` y `@METHOD('PUT')` dentro de tu form para que tus rutas lo detecten y no te genere ese error.

Comment: Asi lo que pasa es que lo tenia en patch pero luego lo cambié a put para ver si asi agarraba y pues al publicarlo se me olvidó cambiarlo

Comment: Sobre el csrf y el @method ya lo intenté y no agarra, sigue igual. Estoy pensando en hacerlo en html puro y pasarle asi los parametros y tendria que crear rutas para cada método.

Comment: Que errores te marca? Y puedes agregar el código de la imagen en texto, porfa, no se alcanza apreciar bien.

Comment: Claro que si, ahi lo pongo. Disculpa si no respondí, estaba ocupado.

Answer (score 0):

Pon en el formulario `method=POST` y dentro de el `@method('PUT')`

Comment: Cuando lo pongo asi, me crea un nuevo registro en vez de actualizarlo, como si no tomara en cuenta el @method

Comment: La url esta bien escrita? `'url' => '/products/'.$product->id` no debería ser `'url' => '/products/update/'.$product->id`?

Comment: Podrias subir la imagen como codigo para que sea mas legible ? @M4G8E5RX

Comment: Claro que si, ahi lo pongo. Disculpa si no respondí, estaba ocupado.

Comment: @M4G8E5RX por cierto, la variable $method que valor tiene ?

Comment: El valor de method se lo paso en la vista de editar: @include('products.form', ['product' => $product, 'url' => '/products/'.$product->id, 'method' => 'PUT'])